# wp redirect to same page in php

Tags: php, wordpress

on my website I restricted 3 pages (IDs 861, 869, 931) to all non-registered users but I'm having a problem, those pages will always redirect the user to the login page (even if I'm logged in), what I'm doing wrong?

Here's the code, a little help would be greatly apprecieated

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_to_specific_page' );

function redirect_to_specific_page() {

if ( is_single('861') or is_single('869') or is_single(931) &&
!is_user_logged_in() ) {

wp_redirect( 'http://mywebsite.com/login', 301 ); 
exit;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you need to scope your order of operations a little better. You first need to check if you're on any of those pages, and THEN if the user is logged in. So:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_to_specific_page' );

function redirect_to_specific_page() {

if ( (is_single('861') || is_single('869') || is_single(931)) &&
     !is_user_logged_in()  ) {
    if ( !is_user_logged_in() ) {   
        wp_redirect( 'http://mywebsite.com/login', 301 ); 
        exit;
    }
}
```

Better yet, you could pass those IDs into the same `is_single()` call:

```
if ( is_single(array(861, 869, 931)) && !is_user_logged_in()  ) {
    if ( !is_user_logged_in() ) {   
        wp_redirect( 'http://mywebsite.com/login', 301 ); 
        exit;
    }
}
```

By the way, why are you using `is_single()` if you're checking pages? Are these custom post types? You might be better off with `is_page()`.

Comment: I've already tried "is_page()" but without result. It seems to work only with "is_single()", any idea why?

Comment: My guess is it's because you're dealing with custom post type. is_single() checks for a single post or custom post type. is_page() checks only pages.

Comment: You might try using is_singular(), which will check all posts, post types, and attachments.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( is_single('861') or is_single('869') or is_single(931) &&
!is_user_logged_in() )
```

Shouldn't it be more like?

```
if ( (is_single('861') || is_single('869') || is_single(931)) &&
    !is_user_logged_in() )
```

[C# conditional AND (&&) OR (||) precedence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196703/c-sharp-conditional-and-or-precedence)

In C# && apparently has higher precedence than ||. Better put it into () just in case.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php

I mean, maybe PHP too.

Answer (score 0):

You if conditional is incorrect. Try this code

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_to_specific_page' );

function redirect_to_specific_page() {

if ( is_single('861') || is_single('869') || is_single(931) ) {
    if ( !is_user_logged_in() ) {   
        wp_redirect( 'http://mywebsite.com/login', 301 ); 
        exit;
    }
}
```