# IF function with && and || at the same time

Tags: c#, if-statement

I want to do IF under serveral condition AND && and OR || on it

i have two range of number
Top1 - Bottom1 and
Top2 - Bottom2

and only executed when Currentnumber is within these two range
am i doing it okay ?

```
if (OnlyAbove == True
    && (Top1 > Currentnumber || Top2 > Currentnumber)
    && (Bottom1 < Currentnumber || Bottom2 < Currentnumber)
   )
{
   Statement
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# conditional AND (&&) OR (||) precedence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196703/c-sharp-conditional-and-or-precedence)

Comment: have you tested it? You should really create unit tests for all the cases

Comment: also should the number be within both of these ranges (aka within the intersection) or within any of those ranges (aka union)?

Comment: If a number is between Bottom1 and Top1, then it must be greater (or greater than or equal to, depending on your rules) Bottom1 _**AND**_ it must be less than (or <=) Top1.  And, if it can be either in one range (using the rules above) _**OR**_ in the other range (using similar rules, but different boundaries).  Write your expressions accordingly.  Use parentheses to make it clear to the reader what you really mean.

Comment: Do you have a member called `True` with capital T? That would be confusing. If you mean the keyword `true`, do not compare a non-nullable Boolean expression to the `true` literal. Instead use `if (OnlyAbove && …)`.

Comment: @Flydog57  i made this && (((Top1 > Currentnumber) && (Bottom1 < Currentnumber)) || (Top2 > Currentnumber) && (Bottom2 < Currentnumber)))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to go out on a limb and say: no, you're not doing right on this one - mostly because what your code is currently doing doesn't make sense.

One thing that helps out with stuff like this is to phrase it in common english - so you go from:

```
if (OnlyAbove == True
    && (Top1 > Currentnumber || Top2 > Currentnumber)
    && (Bottom1 < Currentnumber || Bottom2 < Currentnumber)
   )
{
   Statement
}
```

... to ...

```
if OnlyAbove
    AND (CurrentNumber above at least one of the two Tops)
    AND (CurrentNumber below at least one of the bottoms)
```

After all, the stuff between those inner parenthesis is saying "Top1 > current **OR** Top2 > current"  - which really isn't what you're looking for.

Something that'll help out - not only *writing* code like this, but *reading* it down the line, is to go a bit overboard with variables.  Variables are **awesome** at helping you document logic, since you can name them very descriptively.

So imagine code that looks like this:

```
bool betweenRange1 = (Currentnumber > Bottom1) && (Currentnumber < Top1);
bool betweenRange2 = (Currentnumber > Bottom2) && (Currentnumber < Top2);
if (OnlyAbove && betweenRange1 && betweenRange2)
{
    Statement
}
```

... that IF statement starts to look a lot more readable - it's obvious at a glance at what it's getting at.  If you're having trouble parsing IF statements, it's not a bad habit to get into.  Maybe a bit overkill... but overkill's a lot better than having code you're not sure of what it's doing  :-)

Comment: thank you sir, and your answer help with my phrase too :D