# Operator Logical-AND vs inline if else not compatible

Tags: c#

After a incomprehensible bug, I found a strange behavior of `&&` operator.

I extracted my code:

```
string s = "123";
Console.WriteLine(false && s.Length < 2 ? true : s.Substring(0,2).ToUpper() != "GA");
```

I expected the result is `false`, but it gives me `true`

To receive the expected result, I put the second statement in `()`

```
Console.WriteLine(false && (s.Length<2 ? true : s.Substring(0,2).ToUpper() != "GA"));
```

It gives me `false`

Code tested in [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/L4VZSG)

Someone has passed in same situation ?

Comment: It's not strange behavior nor a bug... it's correct as per precedence and order of evaluation. [See](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196703/c-sharp-conditional-and-or-precedence) that or [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-language/precedence-and-order-of-evaluation?view=vs-2019). Specifically there's this `Operators are listed in descending order of precedence`, please read.

Comment: [Operator precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/). `&&` has higher precedence than `? :`. The first is interpreted as `(false && s.Length < 2) ? x : y`, so `s.Substring(0,2).ToUpper != "GA"` is evaluated, which is `true`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# conditional AND (&&) OR (||) precedence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196703/c-sharp-conditional-and-or-precedence)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This behaviour is correct. Let's see:

```
string s = "123";
Console.WriteLine(false && s.Length < 2 ? true : s.Substring(0,2).ToUpper() != "GA");
```

The expression for the ternary expression is:
    `false && s.Length < 2` // s.Length is 3 => 3 < 2 == false

Therefore the expression `s.Substring(0,2).ToUpper() != "GA"` is executed and returns `true`, as `"12" != "GA"`.

Comment: This is a *decent* answer, but I think can be improved by adding, *why precedence matters and order of evaluation*...

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ: True, I found an article here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5473107/operator-precedence-vs-order-of-evaluation

Answer (score 1):

It was evaluated as `(false && s.Length < 2) ? true : s.Substring(0,2).ToUpper() != "GA"`, in which the conditional is `false`, so ends up as `s.Substring(0,2).ToUpper() != "GA"`, which is true.

Worth noting that if the precedence was as you wanted/expected it to be, the result would always be `false`. Due to short-circuiting, the ternary conditional would never even be executed.